# How do I make a snipe command that shows the timestamp in the footer

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am able to get the time in UTC using the 'pytz' library and 'datetime' library, but I need it in local time of the user. Say you run the snipe command from the USA, you should get your local time, and if I run it from say Italy, I should get Italy's time. I hope I made it clear.

```
x = message = {}
y = author = {}
z = author_avatar = {}
time = {}

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(msg):
    UTC = pytz.utc
    datetime_utc = datetime.now(UTC)   
    


    if msg.author.bot == False:
        x[msg.channel.id] = msg.content
        y[msg.channel.id] = msg.author
        time[msg.channel.id] = datetime_utc.strftime('%H:%M UTC')

    if msg.author == client.user:
        x[msg.channel.id] = msg.content
        y[msg.channel.id] = msg.author
        time[msg.channel.id] = datetime_utc.strftime('%H:%M UTC')

    


@client.command(name = 'snipe')
async def snipe(ctx):
    try:
        em = discord.Embed(description = f"    {x[ctx.channel.id]}" ,color = random.choice(colors_for_embeds1), timestamp = datetime.now())
        em.set_author(name = y[ctx.channel.id] ,icon_url = (y[ctx.channel.id]).author.url)
        em.set_footer(text = f"at {time[ctx.channel.id]}")
        
        
        await ctx.send(embed = em)
    except:
        await ctx.send("There is nothing to snipe!")
```

This is how the command works. The deleted message gets added to a dictionary with the channel ID as the key, the author id gets saved in a dictionary with the channel ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answers your question.

UTC time updates for your location, so for you, it would show your time (example: Today at 8:00 AM) then for someone else that is somewhere else in the world would show (Today at 9:00 AM).

I don't know if I answered this well or not, or if you understood it.
But hope answers your question! :D

Comment: It would be helpful if you could back the explanation with some code implementation in reference to the code provided in the question.

Comment: @AdityaPatnaik all you need to do is 
em = discord.Embed(timestamp = datetime.now())

Answer (score 1):

your bot has no way of knowing the timezone of the people running the command. The timestamp on discord embeds always show the time in the local format for the people who see the embed, so different people will see different times depending on their timezones.

A solution would be to record the user timezone with a different command and save it to a database.

Then on your command parse the time into the footer for the timezone you want.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping, but i need to store the time when the message was deleted. Maybe I'll just keep it UTC.